# Google maps direction summary from API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, directions

Is it possible to get the following summary from the google direction service api:

[image]

There is a summary property returned by the API but it doesn't matcch the summaries on google. (see screen grab)

[image]

Comment: The google directions api doesn't provide "mixed" (driving/transit) results (at least at present).  You could get that information with two requests.

Comment: Hi, I am currently making two requests, one for driving, one for transit.  The issue I have is I can not see where the summary is in the returned object.  For example, 'via m11 and m25'

Comment: Looking at the result in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ucyn9yj9/13/), there is a "summary" for each route (at least when route alternatives are requested, however, it isn't [documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsRoute)).  I see you have discovered that, I'm not suprized it doesn't match what you see on Google Maps, that is different)

Comment: This is what I'm after, thanks.  I'd quite like to be able to get the exact same data that's outputted into the panel, but without any of the markup, so just an object would be ace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Google Maps App != Google Maps APIs and Service

Just to set the correct expectations, you shouldn't expect the Google Maps APIs and Web Services and the Google Maps App to work in the exact same way at all times.

The Google Maps App gathers data from many different sources, such as Wikis, local business listings or Google+ information. The Directions API on the other hand uses a mix of information from the Geocoding API with other APIs to determine the best path to a given location.

### What now?

In short, you can't expect these two different things to return the same, and the Directions API is not equipped to return all the data you are looking for.

You can however try the following:

- Make multiple requests (as you pointed) and use the optional [`alternatives`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters) parameter;
- Mix you data with data from third parties, like Google does.

---

Hope it helps !